# I found some questionable entries in wp-config.php - should these entries be there?

Tags: wordpress

I been working on my web server all day because my cPanel is using like 100% CPU every 5 minutes or so then it goes down to 0 but cause my sites to show 503 code once in awhile.

As I was in the wp-config.php file adding a entry to disable wp-cron.php I also noticed this custom entry, was I hacked? Is this a normal entry?

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');define('FS_CHMOD_DIR',0755);define('FS_CHMOD_FILE',0644);
define('WP_TEMP_DIR',dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-content/uploads');
```

I attached screenshot also. Thank you in advance!

[image: Screenshot of contents of wp-config.php]

I updated all my WordPress sites. I have been getting crushed lately with malicious bots and I use CloudFlare. Updated all my plugins, installed shield security for WordPress , still high I/O usage every five minutes or so, still testing whether disabling wp-cron is helping.

Comment: The only one I'm not sure about is `WP_TEMP_DIR`, the other ones seem harmless. With that being said, none of these PHP constants are included with wp-config.php by default so either someone put them there or a plugin did.

Comment: Yes , Ok thanks - I have never edited the file before , so it could have been a plugin I suppose, is it safe to delete those entries and see how my site behaves and add them back if necessary?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Yep @EcsWest, that should be fine.

Comment: @cabrerahector Thanks for your help! Side note , I found out why my server was using so much resources it was a nulled wordpress plugin on one of the sites

Comment: Ok @Adriaan no problem this was my first time posting I will post better formatted as you suggested next time thx